# how to build a numpy object array (object includes another array)

Tags: arrays, numpy, oop

In another language I like to use object arrays containing every class object, and each object is very efficiently accessible via the object array. I am trying to do the same with Python and numpy. Each object has a number of members of different type, including a numpy array itself. So in the end result I need an object array of all objects which can efficiently be accessed and return any member, most importantly the member array.

I tried something like this:

```
class TestClass():
    objectarray=np.empty([10, 1], dtype=np.object)  ## static array holding all class objects
    def __init__(self,name,position):
        self.name=name
        self.position=position
        self.intmember= 5
        self.floatmember=3.4
        self.arraymember= np.zeros([5, 5])  ## another array which is a member of the class
        TestClass.objectarray[position]=self
```

then:

```
testobj1 = TestClass('test1',5)  ## create a new object and add it at position 5 into the object array
```

Something seems to have happened

```
TestClass.objectarray

array([[None],
       [None],
       [None],
       [None],
       [None],
       [<__main__.TestClass object at 0x000000EF214DC308>],
       [None],
       [None],
       [None],
       [None]], dtype=object)
```

However this doesnt work:

```
a= TestClass.objectarray[5]
a.intmember
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-dac52811af13> in <module>
      1 a= TestClass.objectarray[5]
----> 2 a.intmember

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'intmember'
```

What I am doing wrong? Remember this needs to be an efficient mechanism inside a large loop

(PS (I know I could use a list of objects, but iterating over lists is prohibitively slow in my testing. Hence I want to use numpy arrays, ideally augmented by numba)

Comment: The fast `numpy` code works for numeric dtypes, not object dtype.  In that case it can iterate in compiled code.  But an object dtype array holds references to objects, just like a list does.  Do some basic timings; you'll see, I think, that iteration on an object dtype array is slower (than list iteration).

Comment: I would select the numpy array member and only iterate over that. The rest is just referential data not part of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [1]: class TestClass(): 
   ...:     objectarray=np.empty([10, 1], dtype=np.object)  ## static array holding all class o
   ...: bjects 
   ...:     def __init__(self,name,position): 
   ...:         self.name=name 
   ...:         self.position=position 
   ...:         self.intmember= 5 
   ...:         self.floatmember=3.4 
   ...:         self.arraymember= np.zeros([5, 5])  ## another array which is a member of the c
   ...: lass 
   ...:         TestClass.objectarray[position]=self 
   ...:                                                                                        
In [2]: testobj1 = TestClass('test1',5)
```

As defined `testobj1` has an `intmember` attribute:

```
In [3]: testobj1                                                                               
Out[3]: <__main__.TestClass at 0x7fceba8acef0>
In [4]: testobj1.intmember                                                                     
Out[4]: 5
```

That object has also placed itself in the class array:

```
In [5]: TestClass.objectarray                                                                  
Out[5]: 
array([[None],
       [None],
       [None],
       [None],
       [None],
       [<__main__.TestClass object at 0x7fceba8acef0>],
       [None],
       [None],
       [None],
       [None]], dtype=object)
```

Since that's a 2d array, we have use 2d indexing to reference an element:

```
In [8]: TestClass.objectarray[5,0]                                                             
Out[8]: <__main__.TestClass at 0x7fceba8acef0>
In [9]: TestClass.objectarray[5,0].intmember                                                   
Out[9]: 5
```

Access with `[5]` just indexes on the first dimension; the object still embedded inside an array:

```
In [10]: TestClass.objectarray[5]                                                              
Out[10]: array([<__main__.TestClass object at 0x7fceba8acef0>], dtype=object)
```

I don't think creating a (10,1) array helped; a simple 1d would be just as good:

```
 objectarray=np.empty([10], dtype=np.object)
```

or just a list:

```
In [12]: class TestClass(): 
    ...:     objectarray=[None]*10 
    ...:     def __init__(self,name,position): 
    ...:         self.name=name 
    ...:         self.position=position 
    ...:         self.intmember= 5 
    ...:         self.floatmember=3.4 
    ...:         self.arraymember= np.zeros([5, 5])  ## another array which is a member of the 
    ...: class 
    ...:         TestClass.objectarray[position]=self 
    ...:                                                                                       
In [13]: testobj1 = TestClass('test1',5)                                                       
In [14]: testobj1                                                                              
Out[14]: <__main__.TestClass at 0x7fceac25f5c0>
In [15]: testobj1.objectarray                                                                  
Out[15]: 
[None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 <__main__.TestClass at 0x7fceac25f5c0>,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None]
In [16]: testobj1.objectarray[5]                                                               
Out[16]: <__main__.TestClass at 0x7fceac25f5c0>
In [17]: testobj1.objectarray[5].intmember                                                     
Out[17]: 5
```

Accessing an element of the list is faster than doing the same for the object array:

```
In [18]: timeit Out[5][5,0].intmember                                                          
149 ns ± 0.00964 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
In [19]: timeit Out[15][5].intmember                                                           
90.5 ns ± 0.0478 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

## frompyfunc

I've recommended `np.frompyfunc` as a convenient, if not fast, way of accessing or otherwise working with object dtype arrays.  For example

A function to fetch the `intmember` value if present:

```
In [28]: def getval(item): 
    ...:     try: 
    ...:         return item.intmember 
    ...:     except AttributeError: 
    ...:         return None
```

applied to object array:

```
In [29]: np.frompyfunc(getval,1,1)(Out[5])                                                     
Out[29]: 
array([[None],
       [None],
       [None],
       [None],
       [None],
       [5],
       [None],
       [None],
       [None],
       [None]], dtype=object)
```

applied to list:

```
In [30]: np.frompyfunc(getval,1,1)(Out[15])                                                    
Out[30]: 
array([None, None, None, None, None, 5, None, None, None, None],
      dtype=object)
```

timings:

```
In [31]: timeit np.frompyfunc(getval,1,1)(Out[15])                                             
14.6 µs ± 187 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [32]: timeit np.frompyfunc(getval,1,1)(Out[5])                                              
9.53 µs ± 54 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [33]: [getval(i) for i in Out[15]]                                                          
Out[33]: [None, None, None, None, None, 5, None, None, None, None]
In [34]: timeit [getval(i) for i in Out[15]]                                                   
6.53 µs ± 93.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

list comprehension on the list is fastest.

Comment: ok so I guess its back to lists but I need to understand what you are doing first.

Comment: May I ask a follow up question - and I'd be happy to open a new question if that's better - What if we don't know yet which object we need to pull, but need to iterate over all objects to find the one that matches our condition, e.g. : "Give me the object whose intmember is 5 " is there some efficient magic possible?

Comment: each object has to be queried, same as if were a list.  The 'efficient numpy magic' is for numbers, not general python objects.